# Reading in dataframe with json file in R

Tags: sql, r

I have an SQL database where I want to select a column of JSONfiles and convert it to a readable R dataframe. I succeed in creating a dataframe of the `JSONfiles` from my database, but when I try to read them in with the fromJSON function it doesn't read all the `JSONfiles`.

the `data$products_json` column is a column with in every row a JSON file.

```
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT products_json FROM orders")
data = fetch(rs, n=-1)

library(rjson)

jfile <- fromJSON(data$products_json)
```

Comment: Please show sample of JSON as it depends on structure to migrate the nested, tree type into two dimensions of dataframe. Also, please mention your RDBMS (SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) as methods may be available to query JSON into tabular format. Since, SQL is a language, *SQL Database* is akin to saying *English book*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to collapse all JSON docs into one big JSON array. This will result in a structure that jsonlite can handle. Jsonlite also has a fromJSON function that makes it very easy to transform a JSON array into an R dataframe.

In your case this would be:

```
library(jsonlite)

# This will collapse the products_json into one string that represents a json_array
partial_array <- paste(data$products_json,  collapse = ', ')
json_array <- paste('[', partial_array, ']')

jfile <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_array)
```

Where products_json is a column of JSON docs in data